# Software for simulating the motion of a test particle in a force field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, resource-recommendations, simulations, software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software for simulating 3D Newtonian dynamics of simple geometric objects (with force fields)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12560/software-for-simulating-3d-newtonian-dynamics-of-simple-geometric-objects-with)

Is there any software for linux, which can simulate the motion of a test particle in a force field.

I.e. I want to define a force field and the initial definitions of the test particle and the software simulates the moving particle (based on the (numerical) solutions of the corresponding differential equations of motion).

Would be great if the software could display the vector field and the field lines as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12560/2451

Comment: I suggest: any programming language.